# Access SQL Distinct max value

Tags: sql, ms-access

Been stumbling over this for hours now. I've looked at several other articles on here but cant find one that fits my needs. Have an Access database where i am attempting to remove possible duplicates and also get the max values for a unique list. I have a few fields with needed data:

> CustomerNumber EmpID SurveyResultID SurveyTotalScore SurveyQuestionCount

CustomerNumber has duplicates but i need distinct values only. If there is a duplicate CustomerNumber with different SurveyTotalScore, i need the MAX score.

Essentially i want to return a list of distinct CustomerNumber with the highest SurveyTotalScore and no duplicates. What's the best way?

**Update:**
Here is one query i've tried. It works if i just leave CustomerNumber by itself but i need the EmpID and some other fields.

```
SELECT CustomerNumber, Max(SurveyTotalScore) AS MaxScore, SurveyResultID
FROM CSATDetail
GROUP BY CustomerNumber, SurveyResultID;
```

> Example Data:

```
+----------------+----------+----------------+-------+
| CustomerNumber | MaxScore | SurveyResultID | EmpID |
+----------------+----------+----------------+-------+
|            259 |       40 |         461500 |    83 |
|            259 |       38 |         461501 |    83 |
|            695 |       40 |         461502 |    59 |
|            695 |       40 |         461504 |    59 |
|            734 |       40 |         461503 |    96 |
+----------------+----------+----------------+-------+
```

What i'd like to have come out is this. It selects the maxscore and doesn't have duplicates if there is more than one result for an EmpID

```
+----------------+----------+----------------+-------+
| CustomerNumber | MaxScore | SurveyResultID | EmpID |
+----------------+----------+----------------+-------+
|            259 |       40 |         461500 |    83 |
|            695 |       40 |         461502 |    59 |
|            734 |       40 |         461503 |    96 |
+----------------+----------+----------------+-------+
```

Comment: You have to determine which column/s that makes the record duplicating. Then you have to choose which of those values should be picked instead of the others. You have to make rules for deduplication.

Comment: There is only one column that cannot have a duplicate value, which is SurveyResultID. I can get a list of Distinct CustomerNumber but I also need the max SurveyTotalScore if there are duplicates.

Comment: This can easily be done with rank or row_number window functions but they don't exist in access sql. So any chance you can use different database ? even mssql  ?

Comment: I wish I could, but unfortunately I'm stuck with access. When I think about it, it seems like it should be pretty easy. I've tried various sub queries and DMax but not getting the results I need. I get the correct SurveyTotalScore if I only look at distinct CustomerNumber and max SurveyTotalScore. However, if I bring in the SurveyResultID since it's a unique value it brings back all results.

Comment: Please, please, please show us your SQL attempt and example data. Are you really, really sure they are duplicates or just *Customers* who filled out multiple *Surveys* for the same/different *Employee* and hence their join will repeat values?

Comment: When I get back in front of a PC tomorrow I'll post my attempt. Essentially a customer should only have one survey "count" , and it should be the highest score if there are multiples.

Comment: What is the schema of your tables? Is the narrative as I commented correct? Does *Customers* share one-to-many with *Surveys* table? Whenever you SQL join this type of relationship, customers will repeat for each distinct survey. These are not duplicates.

Comment: What am I missing? Sounds like a GROUP BY aggregate. `SELECT CustomerNumber, Max(SurveyTotalScore) AS MaxScore FROM tablename GROUP BY CustomerNumber;`. Otherwise, build a report and use its Sorting & Grouping features with aggregate calcs. Report allows display of detail data as well as summary calcs.

Comment: If a report is not approach you want and you want to retrieve the record with the max score, review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#TopN

Comment: Updated post to include sample data and query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're one step away.

- Generate a set with the max total and customerID (looks like you don't need/want surveyID in that).  (check, with a little tweak)
- Then join it back to the base set to get the info you need. This limits the results of the full set of data by those with just the max total allowing you to get the other needed info. (Just need this!)

.

```
SELECT CD.CustomerNumber, MaxScore, min(SurveyResultID), EmpID 
FROM CSATDETAIL CD
INNER JOIN (SELECT CustomerNumber, Max(SurveyTotalScore) AS MaxScore
            FROM CSATDetail CI
            GROUP BY CustomerNumber) CD2
  on CD.CustomerNumber = CD2.customerNumber
 and CD.SurveyTotalScore = CD2.MaxScore
GROUP BY CD.CustomerNumber, MaxScore, EmpID
```

and since it appears you can have ties based on sample data and you want the min survey..... we needed a group by and min.

----After last comment... this basically now says.

Return the employeeID for each customer having the highest score with the earliest surveyResultID.

```
SELECT CD.CustomerNumber, MaxScore, minSurveyResultID, EmpID 
FROM CSATDETAIL CD
INNER JOIN (SELECT CD3.CustomerNumber, CD2.MaxScore, Min(SurveyResultID) AS MinSurveyResultID
            FROM CSATDETAIL CD3
            INNER JOIN (SELECT CustomerNumber, Max(SurveyTotalScore) AS MaxScore
                        FROM CSATDetail CI
                        GROUP BY CustomerNumber) CD2
               ON CD2.CustomerNumber = Cd3.CustomerNumber
              and CD2.MaxScore = CD3.SurveyTotalScore
            GROUP BY CD3.CustomerNumber, CD2.MaxScore) CD4

  on CD.CustomerNumber = CD4.customerNumber
 and CD.SurveyTotalScore = CD4.MaxScore
 and CD.SurveyResultID = CD4.MinSurveyResultID
```

Comment: When i use this i still get all results.

Comment: Just modified to exclude surveyID from the inner select and join  after reading comments and reviewing closer, you don't want it.  so @camaroracer016 how about now? :P  However if a customer has the same score more than once, all such records having a max score per customer would be returned.  Also, change * to the desired fields.  Really shouldn't use * except on exists or a few other places on code.

Comment: That looks like it removes the duplicates where there is a different score-Great! Now- how do i go about removing duplicates when they have the same score?

Comment: Done :P  looks like you want min surveyResultID when such an example exists.  Just needed to add a min and a group by and specify the * fields :P

Comment: I feel like we are so close! However with that, i get an error: "The specified field 'CustomerNumber' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement."

Comment: Prefix customerNumber with CD in select and group by.  Also I"m a bit curious how employeeID relates to CustomerNumber; but we should be close.  The reason I'm curious is if a customer could have two different employee numbers for the same survey with the same max score; and you'd only want one of them...  In which case this gets a bit more complex. as I need to know the rules which govern which one you'd want.

Comment: Awesome! Looks like that does the trick. Removes the duplicates and also select the higher score where applicable. This does allow a customer to submit a survey in a given period for multiple employees which as of right now, is how i need it. If i need to only select for one employee, perhaps the "newest" survey which can be derived by a max survey ID (they are sequential) how could i do that?

Comment: added a block for such a situation.  Nesting queries to get max score with min survey result ID.  you need each subset to be generated since if you simply did min SurveyResult with Max Score you may get a max score which was not on that min survey.  Thus the need for subqueries.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the second query above. It looked like it's missing a comma after the first Min() but after i add it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure; no comma needed after the min as MinsurveyResultID is an alias not another comma. II can't see anything wrong after a re-review...  do you get an error message or just invalid syntax?